# List class properties with superclass properties first

Tags: matlab, class, properties, cell-array

In Matlab, when I call `properties('MyClass')`, it creates a cell array with subclass properties first, and superclass properties last. Is it possible to have the array in the other way around, with superclass properties first?

I don't want to just reverse the whole array, because it'll reverse the order of properties *within* the super/sub class.

I want to turn

`'Sub1','Sub2','Super1','Super2'`

into

`'Super1','Super2', 'Sub1','Sub2'`

Comment: You could investigate the meta class: `mc = meta.class.fromName('MyClass')`, then `mc` will contain the property `PropertyList`, which contains all properties that have been defined in the class hierarchy. Each property has itself a property called `DefiningClass`, which contains the meta class object for, well, the class where the property was defined. You can collect both property names and defining class names, and reorder by defining class.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on my comment:
The meta class contains information about the properties and which parent class defined them. The idea is then to go through properties, by defining class, and collect property names while reversing class order but keeping order within class.

```
mkl = meta.class.fromName('MyClass');

% get number of properties and populate cell to hold names
n = numel(mkl.PropertyList);
pl = cell(n, 2);

for ii = 1:n
    pl{ii, 1} = mkl.PropertyList(ii).Name;
    pl{ii, 2} = mkl.PropertyList(ii).DefiningClass.Name;
end

% find unique defining classes, keeping their sort order
klasses = unique(pl(:,2), 'stable');
new_prop_list = {};
% go through class list in reverse, find defined properties, and append them 
for ii = numel(klasses):-1:1
    klass = klasses{ii};
    kl_prop = strcmpi(klass, pl(:,2));
    new_prop_list = [new_prop_list; pl(kl_prop, 1)];
end
```